# OpenCV Python count pixels

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working with a little project with application of `OpenCV` and I'm stuck with something that I don't know how to implement. Suppose I have an image (`1024x768`). In this image there is a red bounding box at the center.

Is it possible to count the pixels inside the red box using `OpenCS`? given that the image is `1024x768` in dimension.

I tried to use bounding rectangle by thresholding the red color and tried using `convexhull` but then I can't extract how many pixels are inside the red marker.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's simple. Clearly the inner gray and outer colour are different. just threshold the image.

```
ret,thresh=cv2.threshold(img,133,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

Then use:

```
cv2.countNonZero(your_thresh_img)
```

That gives you the number of white pixels, which is the count you need. In your Image, it was 183920 pixels.

**Edit**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img=cv2.imread("your_image.png",0)

def nothing(x):
  pass

cv2.namedWindow('image')

cv2.createTrackbar('min','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('max','image',0,255,nothing)

while(1):

 a = cv2.getTrackbarPos('min','image')
 b = cv2.getTrackbarPos('max','image')
 ret,thresh=cv2.threshold(img,a,b,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
 cv2.imshow("output",thresh)
 k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF
 if k == 27:
    break
print cv2.countNonZero(thresh)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: edited and added the threshold values. Sorry, earlier i did wrong thresholding. updated the new value.

Comment: hi I.Newton :) thank you for answering . I got the idea :) ahmmm for additional, what if the center is not a plain color gray? say it is a picture of rocks and sand? is there other way to achieve same output?

Comment: in that case you threshold the red border and then do whatever the operations required, like 1024*768- value etc.

Comment: There are lot of methods depending on what exactly you want and how the image looks

Comment: i'll edit and add code for a Trackbar you can play with to set threshold values. :)

Comment: is it possible to threshold the red border as enclosed square? i mean not just the border

Comment: it depends on what the image inside box looks like compared to out. Or best, do this threshold the box and flood fill the outer regions. That gives what you want. Also can find contours and use -1 as argument and a lot of other methods.

Comment: ohhh nicee i got the idea , i will look into it :) thank youu so much for the help but :)